# Save textbox value, VBA, Excel

Tags: excel, forms, vba, textbox, save

I'm writing a code for excel, that will have a form witch include a textbox and button.
Button selects a folder directory and writes it in textbox. 
Part of the form is this!

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MASBP.jpg)

The code for it is this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Title = "Select a folder then hit OK"
diaFolder.Show
TextBox1.Text = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
Set diaFolder = Nothing

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
Msg = "No folder selected, you must select a folder for program to run"
Style = vbError
Title = "Need to Select Folder"
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)

End Sub
```

The problem is how to save the "textbox" value to show it every time I call the userform; it should't depend on a cell in workbook as it will be an add-in and will be called from the ribbon button.

Any ideas will be appreciated very much !
Thanks.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917977/alternatives-to-public-variables-in-vba) might help.

Comment: The addin itself has an associated workbook and sheets.  You can store the value there.  Would this work for you?

Comment: Addin has it's sheet (for example sheet1), but how to link a cell in that sheet without "disturbing" the actual active workbook?

Comment: Use `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("SomeRange")` to store and access a value.  `Thisworkbook` refers to the workbook containing the VBA code executing, in this instance the addin.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll try it and will write comment about the result.

Comment: Ioannis, thanks for the link.

Comment: chris neilsen it works, but the problem is how to save it ? ))))

Comment: Ok I found it. `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True` command will do that.
Thanks you all very much!!!

Comment: You can save text strings up to 255 characters in a workbook's `CustomDocumentProperties` collection, then you can read from that collection, too.