# Save user form input value for next time edit

Tags: userform

Will the solution provided in the solution [Save userform value for next time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950197/save-userform-value-for-next-time) work for word documents as well?

Comment: which solution in that question? perhaps you should try it yourself first? if you have, did you ask because you faced some problems?

Comment: The last solution from Variatus.  I have many list boxes and text boxes in my form and wanted to make sure that the solution would apply to word documents as well before endeavouring down this road.  My problem is that this document that contains the user form with text boxes etc. will be used many times for different projects with different directory addresses.

Comment: I have tried the code in word but the user form does not retain the information in the list boxes etc. in the next opening session.  Gives a error message -   MsgMe Dir(Ffn & "\", vbDirectory) & ", " & Len(Dir(Ffn & "\", vbDirectory)) - sun or function not defined.