# How to read / work with custom Document Properties?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a project in which I need to save a few variables, that i can use on every opening of my workbook, without the need to set it up manually on startup.

To create a custom document property, I am using the example-code provided by Microsoft on their official website.

**Question:**
After setting up the properties, I am accessing them by opening an `item(x)`. The number `x` seems to depend on the alphabetical order of my property's name.

Is there a way to read and to work with a property, opening it by its name?

```
Sub InitializeCustomProperty()     
    Dim wksSheet1 As Worksheet     
    Set wksSheet1 = Application.ActiveSheet

    ' Add metadata to worksheet.
    wksSheet1.CustomProperties.Add _
      Name:="Computer 1", Value:="computername"
End Sub


Sub Add_My_Computer1()
    ' sets the value of my custom property (i"ve found out its Item(1) by outputting my properties 
    Dim sHostName2 As String
    sHostName2 = Environ$("computername")
    Worksheets(1).CustomProperties.Item(1).Value = sHostName2
End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend to save your properties in a worksheet instead, and make this worksheet hidden.

Comment: Want to draw your attention to the fact that the worksheet related `CustomProperties` collection doesn't mean the same as the workbook related `CustomDocumentProperties` you are asking for in the question's title. - See [MS help: Excel.Workbook.CustomDocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.customdocumentproperties)

Comment: Further links: [How to add a DocumentProperty to CustomDocumentProperties in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863250/how-to-add-a-documentproperty-to-customdocumentproperties-in-excel), [Chip Pearsons site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/docprop.aspx) and a related theme at SO [Check if BuiltInDocumentProperty is set without error trapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766268/check-if-builtindocumentproperty-is-set-without-error-trapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea if there's a simpler way, but the following Function returns the CustomProperty by it's name:

```
Function PropertyByName(PropertyName) As CustomProperty
    Dim x As CustomProperty
    For Each x In Worksheets(1).CustomProperties
        If x.Name = PropertyName Then
            Set PropertyByName = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

You can read it with..

```
?PropertyByName("Computer 1").Value
```

Or you can write to it with..

```
PropertyByName("Computer 1").Value = Environ$("computername")
```

It could do with some error checking if the name isn't found, and perhaps the Worksheet could be passed as a parameter but hopefully you get the idea..

Comment: Thanks for the idea! This is probably the work-around i would use!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a defined name of either workbook or worksheet scope that is hidden from normal view.

```
Sub InitializeCustomNames()
    Dim wksSheet1 As Worksheet

    ' Add defined name to workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="wb1USR", _
                           RefersTo:=Chr(61) & Chr(34) & Environ("USERNAME") & Chr(34), _
                           Visible:=False

    ' Add defined name(s) to specific worksheet
    Set wksSheet1 = Worksheets("sheet5")
    wksSheet1.Names.Add Name:="ws1CN", _
                        RefersTo:=Chr(61) & Chr(34) & Environ("COMPUTERNAME") & Chr(34), _
                        Visible:=False
End Sub

Sub retrieveCustonNames()

    Debug.Print Split(ThisWorkbook.Names("wb1USR"), Chr(34))(1)

    Debug.Print Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet5").Names("ws1CN"), Chr(34))(1)

End Sub
```

On Sheet5 in A1:A2,

```
=ws1CN
=wb1USR
```

These will *not* be visible within the Formulas, Defined Names, Name Manager but they could be if you used *Visible:=True*.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I would prefer the idea CLR has posted, but thank you for your help!