# VBA: BeforeDoubleClick from personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, vba

i'd like to do the following: I want to be able to modify the BeforeDoubleClick Event in my personal.xlsb.
Here is an example for what I have in mind: I want, that when I doubleclick a cell, its backgroundcolour is set to green. Usually I would have to do this in the Workbooks Workbook_BeforeDoubleClick Event, however I want to be able to do that in any workbook and from my personal.xlsb, so that I can assign different methods to the BeforeRightClick Event. Ideally I would have a userform with a few buttons, each one assigning a different method to the BeforeRightClick Event.

Is this possible? I was not able to find a solution online.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with a few lines of code in the `ThisWorkbook` module of your Personal file:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print "RightClick on Sheet: " & Sh.Name & " at " & Target.Address
End Sub
```

(note that after adding the code, you have to save, close Excel completely and restart it so that the `Workbook_Open` event is fired).

However, there are two things to consider:

1. When you set `Cancel = True`, you steal all the context menus - I would not recommend to do so. However, if you set `Cancel = False`, there will be two actions in parallel, first your action, and only after that action is finished (which may be a long time when you show a form), the context menu will pop up - very confusing.
2. There are several cases where global Vars are reset, see discussion here: [What is the lifetime of a global variable in excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041138/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-global-variable-in-excel-vba) Once one of these events happens, your `app` variable is reset and from that point on the events will no longer fire until you restart Excel.

My suggestion: Assign a Keyboard Shortcut to a Macro in your personal workbook. Instead of Right Click, the event to fire would be for example `Ctrl+Shift+F` to **F**ormat your worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible - to do this you need to capture `Application` events.

A full explanation with sample code is available here:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx