# Access Dictionary in Different Subs in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, visibility

I want to store some status in VBA (Excel) using a dictionary but got problems with accesing it in a different sub.

in the end, I want a nested Dictionary containing ID's as primary keys and for each ID I want multiple status-messages with the matching timestamp:

```
Example: {ID_1: {status_1: 09.10.19 06:47, status_2: 09.10.19 07:00,...}, ID_2:{status_6: 09.10.19 06:30, status_1: 09.10.19 06:20}}
```

So far I was just trying to get a simple dictionary only containing the ID and the status:

```
Option Explicit  Public dict As Scripting.Dictionary  Public id As Integer


Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Fin

    Dim current_status As String

    current_status = Tabelle4.Range("B11").Value
    id = Tabelle3.Cells(7, 6).Value

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C12:G12")) Is Nothing Then


        If dict Is Nothing Then
            Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

            dict.Add (id), current_status

        'Checks if inner dict exists
        ElseIf Not dict(id).Exists Then

            dict.Add (id), current_status

        End If

    End If

    Fin:

         Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Please note that I change the ID manually and current_status will be generated in B11 by changing one of the values in C12 to G12 (that is why I used Change event).
In the End I want to keep a record of all the status updates that occur and track when they occur.

My Problem is that this does work for 1 Entry. I am able to create one entry in the "If dict is Nothing Then"-part and can access it even after the event. (e.g. inserting MsgBox dict(ID) at the start before triggering the event again.)
I also want to print the result using a Button on my Excel.
However, when I call:

```
Public Sub print_dict()    

MsgBox dict(id)

End Sub
```

I get an error message that dict is not defined. "MsgBox id" yields an empty MsgBox.

Maybe someone can help me out. I am pretty new to VBA and am still struggling with it :D

Cheers!

Comment: 1) Are you sure `print_dict()` gets called after the `Worksheet_Change` event has been triggered at least once? 2) See [What is the lifetime of a global variable in excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7041138/4934172).

Comment: yes pretty sure. I did the event in debug mode 2 times and added "MsgBox dict(id)" at the first line before the second run and it yield the correct "current_status" and id when running the event again.
However, it breaks when changing the id or when trying to acces the dict in the different sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict(id).Exists
```

should be

```
dict.Exists(id)
```

When using an error handler it's worth making sure you're not just skipping over problems with your code syntax.

I'm guessing `MsgBox dict(id)` fails because that sub is in a regular module and not in your sheet module.

```
MsgBox sheetCodename.id
```

should work though.

`MsgBox id` gives you an empty messagebox because you're not using `Option Explicit` in your regular code module: the variable `id` doesn't exist in a scope which can be accessed by your Sub , but without `Option Explicit` your code auto-creates a (blank) `id` variable for you.