# Public variable loses value

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning how to use public variables in my excel projects, at this moment I am running into the following problem:
I am declaring my variable in a single module as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Public Pass_H As String
Public Pass_L As String
```

At the beginning of the project I declare as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
Pass_H = Sheets("Pass").Range("C4").Value
Pass_L = Sheets("Pass").Range("F4").Value
```

And I use it in other projects of other sheets for example:

```
Private Sub CB_3_Click()
Dim Final_T As Range, Final_N As Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set Final_T = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)
    Set Final_N = Final_T.End(xlDown)
    .Unprotect Pass_H
    .Range("A1", Final_N).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .Protect (Pass_H)
End With
End Sub
```

Or:

```
Private Sub Blo()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Protect (Pass_H)
    Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But even in these simple lines the value is lost at some point and it appears as nothing. I already went through the rest of the project and the only statement or reference is in the Workbook.Open()
I don't understand what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Public variables only work on the same execution, if you stop the execution (this means the original execution ended which will be the workbook open event) they just don't exist.

Comment: In fact, they continue to work in the aforementioned projects, but there comes a time when it loses its value, but after several uses.

Comment: I'd advise against public variables whenever possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the execution continues somehow, the public variables stop as soon as you end the routine (they don't continue to exist/hold values after the routine has been stopped). This means, a public variable won't exist indefinitely for the workbook just because it was computed once.

Comment: Would you rather call a Public Sub? 
`Public Sub Pass()
    Pass_H = Sheets("Pass").Range("C4").Value
End Sub`
And
`Sheets("Pass").Pass`
Still a Public Variable tho but i guess you refresh the value

Comment: @Sgdva perhaps read [Understanding the lifetime of variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-the-lifetime-of-variables), and [Understanding Scope and Visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility)

Comment: I read the first one already, going to read the other one thnx.

Comment: Why not just create a function that returns the value as needed, instead of storing it in a public variable. Such as, `Function GetPass()
    GetPass = Range("C4").Value
End Function`
To test it, you can just call:
`Sub test()
    Debug.Print GetPass()
End Sub`

Comment: Or create a property in that sheet.

Comment: @Sgdva sorry,  but you are wrong.  Public variables do hold their values between executions.  They are reset for example by unhandled errors,  or executing an `End`

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041138/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-global-variable-in-excel-vba/7043901#7043901

Comment: @BigBen I am testing the function and it seems to be working quite well, if it is not annoying, do you have any article on why they do not recommend the use of public variables? I would appreciate it.